# Groovy/grails object properties field names

Tags: grails, groovy

I have an object called Termin, when I print it I get the following values

```
println(Termin)
 #1   User123  20.00 Home
```

How can I print the properties field names like this for example:

```
user_id user_name time location
```

Comment: Is Termin a domain object?

Comment: Yes it is. But I want to get the values without looking in the domain class!

Comment: Can you show a simple example

Comment: I cannot right now, I am using my mobile. You said Termin is a domain object right? Can you try Termin.properties.each{println it}? I am not sure you get what you want, but I cannot test it right now.

Comment: Bingo. You got the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do:

```
def propNames = grailsApplication.getDomainClass( 'Termin' ).properties*.name
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the code below to get properties for domains:

```
Shop.class.getDeclaredFields().grep { !it.synthetic && !Modifier.isStatic(it.getModifiers())}.name
```

Answer (score 1):

names and value...

```
object.properties.each { k,v->
  println "${k} | ${v}"
}
```